# Laravel 5.5 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

After installing Laravel 5.5 for a new project, I get this error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

.env db connection info:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lavavelproject
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Dev environment: Windows
PHP 7.0

Comment: Change localhost to 127.0.0.1 and ensure your MySQL has been started

Comment: Can you login to the mysql server using the CLI. `mysql -uhomestead -psecret` ?

Comment: What are the contents of config/database.php ?

Comment: @astroanu What makes you think he is using homestead?

Comment: It appears to work after changing localhost to 127.0.0.1, ran `php artisan cache:clear` and ofcourse restarted MySQL. @Option's solution seems to have worked.

Comment: @nara, added it as an answer for you to tick for others to use in future if they get stuck.

Comment: @Amarnasan what makes you think he's not using Homestead ? :D the idea is to figure out the cli arguments by himself. My comment was not an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sometimes the most common issue is using `localhost`, change this to `127.0.0.1` and it should work for you.

Sometimes you will have to run:

`php artisan cache:clear` and in the rare moments as I have found also running `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: I was throwing this error after a git push to my Azure Linux web app - this answer worked for me via SSH. Cheers @Option !

Comment: Sorry I'm new to PHP Laravel, can I know where to change local to 12.0.0.1? 
Please guide me.

Answer (score 19):

Try to clear cache by terminal:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Do it always when you change config file.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. The solution was to change   `DB_HOST=mariadb`   to   `DB_HOST=localhost`.

If it matters, my localhost is 127.0.0.1.

Anyway, **for my project and my PC config, the problem comes from Apache (XAMP), I think.** 
My project run in Docker containers. 
I put in my ".env" file above two lines, 
`DB_HOST=mariadb` 
`#DB_HOST=localhost`. 
The last line (localhost) is commented and not change when I run the project.
For running `php artisan` commands, I'll deactivate "mariadb" and activate "localhost".
Simple trick to not change much.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, changing `DB_HOST=mysql` to `DB_HOST=localhost` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**On your application** *.env* should be pointing to the IP of your database. Your database is the same server as your Laravel application, it should be:

**.env**

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
```